# download a file from AWS S3 URL using axios response [VueJs]

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, vue.js, amazon-s3, axios

So i have achieve to get the file URL from s3 bucket with axios and in console i can click the url and it will download the file, my question is how to achieve it without click the url from console? so when i press the download button from client it will also proceed to auto click the url as a response

this is what shown in the console [img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ybew0.png)

here is my code to get the url :

```
 exportProductPrice(priceSetID, productSalability, productCategoryStatus) {
                
                this.$http.get("/price/product_price/export?export=1", {params:{
                    // embeds:'price_set_id,product.salability,product.category.status',
                    conditions: priceSetID + productSalability + productCategoryStatus
                }}).then(response => {
                    console.log(response.data.file,'hit')
                    var fileURL = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([responses.data]));
                    var fileLink = document.createElement('a');

                      fileLink.href = fileURL;
                      fileLink.setAttribute('download');
                      document.body.appendChild(fileLink);

                      fileLink.click();
                }).catch((err) => {
                    return Promise.reject({ Error: 'something went wrong', err});
                });
            },
```